# Where / how does Apache generate the HTML code used in the default directory listing?

Tags: apache-http-server, directory-listing

I am looking to modify the HTML that apache generates for its default directory listing.

I already know how to create a HEADER.html file that gets included for every directory listing. I am attempting to change the actual html that Apache generates for the file listing itself; right now my MacOS apache generates this for example:

```
<table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="ios-prototype/">ios-prototype/</a>         </td><td align="right">07-Dec-2012 16:47  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="magneto-git/">magneto-git/</a>           </td><td align="right">07-Dec-2012 16:46  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
```

I want a different HTML structure (like, say, an OL) generated when my server spits back directory listings. (FYI I'm doing a bunch of mobile browser prototyping with my local webserver & need to make it not totally horrible to browse with fingers to the right test directory — the table structure sucks, and while I can mod a lot of it with CSS it's still going to be ganky.)

Comment: You may get an answer here but I recommend asking on the apache mailing list.

Comment: My guess is it's going to be in the source of Apache itself.  Have you checked it yet?

Comment: @techie007 No idea how to check Apache's source code without very specific instructions. Weird that it's buried rather than in some sort of config file.

Comment: Download the source from Apache's web site, open it in a text editor and start searching. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as "How do I customize the directory listing page shown by Apache when there is no index file?"

If I'm correct, this link has the instructions:
http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

Quick directions are:

1) Edit the site config (example: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default) and add these lines between the  lines:

> Options +Indexes
>
> IndexOptions FancyIndexing IgnoreCase VersionSort SuppressHTMLPreamble
>
> HeaderName /relative/path/to/header.html

(The header.html will be loaded based on the current BROWSED directory. With these instructions you'll need to have a header.html in each directory you want to customize. You can also choose to do it only for one directory using .htaccess)

2) Reload Apache (sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload)

3) Create the header.html file in the desired directory. There is example code and style in the link (since I can't paste code here).

Reload your page in your browser and you it should be customized. I tested both of these on Ubuntu 12.04 just now.

Edit: I've changed this answer significantly, so Ellen B's comment no longer applies, sorry. It's a better answer, though, and tested.)

Comment: Huh. So this is using XSL [kill me now] that the browser will transform into whatever HTML I want? I already know about the header.html — the problem is that something deep in Apache is spitting out a TABLE HTML element and I don't want it to. I may check this out but it's prob not worth the time to mess with XSL for me...